# InDesign object model: number of current page

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

There is cursor on the page (one page - one text frame) in inDesign.

Is it possible with JavaScript to get number/id of current page (text frame) with cursor?

Probably solution `app.activeWindow.activePage.name` returns number of the page on the screen, but not number of page/text frame with cursor.

For example: if cursor set on page 3, but we see page 20 on the screen, `app.activeWindow.activePage.name` returns 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`activeWindow`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_LayoutWindow.html) indeed is the page that is *visible* in your current view, and you can scroll away from the text cursor.

To get the page that a cursor is in, first get the object that contains the cursor (usually a text frame) and then read its [`parentPage`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_TextFrame.html#parentPage) property:

> readonly The page on which this page item appears.

Untested but it should be as easy as

```
pagenr = app.selection[0].parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.name;
```

where `app.selection[0]` is the current selection (for a 'clicked but not selected' text cursor its length is always 1), the `parentTextFrames[0]` refers to the frame containing the text and cursor, and then it's a short hop up to the `parentPage` and its properties.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! It was very useful!